# create dictionary while iterating over files and creating multiple dictionary entries for each file

Tags: python, xml, for-loop, elementtree

I have a set of files in a path and am iterating over each file using a for loop. A file might look like this:

- File 1

```
<mets>
<identifier type="1"></identifier>
<title>1. München, 26.03.1841; Bl. 1r-3v</title>
<files>
<file ID="item_0" href="161_Bl_1r.jpg"></file>
<file ID="item_1" href="161_Bl_1v.jpg"></file>
<file ID="item_2" href="161_Bl_2r.jpg"></file>
</files>
</mets>
```

- File 2

```
<mets>
<identifier type="2"></identifier>
<title>2. München, 26.03.1841; Bl. 1r-3v</title>
<files>
<file ID="item_0" href="162_Bl_1r.jpg"></file>
<file ID="item_1" href="162_Bl_1v.jpg"></file>
<file ID="item_2" href="162_Bl_2r.jpg"></file>
</files>
</mets>
```

And my code looks like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

def flatten(l):
    return [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
    
path = r'C:\programming1\Schelling\test'
    
metsImagesAll = []
metDict = {}
    
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".xml"):
        fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)
        # #getting the root of each file as my starting point
    for file in fullpath:
        tree = ET.parse(fullpath)
        root = tree.getroot()
        metimagesFile = []
   
    for child in root[2]:
        metimagesFile.append(child.attrib["href"])
    metsImagesAll.append(metimagesFile)
    AllMetsImageList = flatten(metsImagesAll)
    metstitle = root[1].text
    metsIdentifier = root[0].attrib["type"]
    for x in AllMetsImageList:
        metDict[x] = [metstitle, metsIdentifier]
```

However, when running metDict I just get a dictionary with the different keys but where all the titles and identifiers are the same. I have tried a few different variants of this for loop but never get it right.

This is what I get currently:

```
{'161_Bl_1r.jpg': ['2. München, 26.03.1841; Bl. 1r-3v', '2'],
 '161_Bl_1v.jpg': ['2. München, 26.03.1841; Bl. 1r-3v', '2'],
 '161_Bl_2r.jpg': ['2. München, 26.03.1841; Bl. 1r-3v', '2'],
 '162_Bl_1r.jpg': ['2. München, 26.03.1841; Bl. 1r-3v', '2'],
 '162_Bl_1v.jpg': ['2. München, 26.03.1841; Bl. 1r-3v', '2'],
 '162_Bl_2r.jpg': ['2. München, 26.03.1841; Bl. 1r-3v', '2']}
```

but I want a dictionary where the titles and identifiers change according to what the title and identifier are in the file that the link was found. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: I think your indentation needs fixing; right now it looks like all your code is defining `flatten`.  Also not sure why you're importing collections, it doesn't seem to be used anywhere.

Comment: I think the reason you keep getting '2. München, 26.03.1841...' is because you have the same jpeg filenames in both xml files, so the last file you process sets the value for the key, which is the same filename as in the previous file, so it gets overwritten.

Comment: @MrFelixU I made the edits you suggested. The jpeg filenames are a bit different in the different xml files in file 1 they begin with 161 and in file 2 they begin with 162. I am getting all the jpeg filenames but than the title and identifier are only being taken from the last file but I am not sure how to create a dictionary where I get all of them. This would require to make multiple dictionary entries with different key, but the same value since each file has only one title and identifier but multiple jpeg files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a much simpler solution to the problem. I just access all the information in the initial for loop when I am getting the image files and create the dict in there. So for every image, I am automatically getting a copy of the title and identifier and saving it directly:

```
path = r'C:\programming1\Schelling\test'

metDict = {}

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".xml"):
        fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)
        # #getting the root of each file as my starting point
    for file in fullpath:
        tree = ET.parse(fullpath)
        root = tree.getroot()


    for child in root[2]:
        metDict[child.attrib["href"]] = [root[1].text, root[0].attrib["type"]]
```